# spelling error will not go to error

Tags: batch-file

During my game if I spell something wrong, for example "go south" it will just close the batch file instead of going to echo error.Here is part of the code I have the problem on.

```
:type
set /p menu=type:
if "%menu%" == "go north" goto north
if "%menu%" == "go south" goto south
if "%menu%" == "go east" goto east
if "%menu%" == "go west" goto west
if "%menu%" == "grab bandage" goto pick up
if "%menu%" == "use bandage" goto use
if "%menu%" == "inventory" goto inventory
if "%menu%" == "look around" goto look around
if "%menu%" == "open drawer" goto open drawer
if "%menu%" == "open tin can" goto open can
if "%menu%" == "take tin can" goto ttc
if "%menu%" == "take key" goto tk
if "%menu%" == "take money" goto take money
if "%menu%" == "throw can" goto throw
echo error
pause
cls
goto play
```

It should go down the chooses until it reaches echo error.If I spell something wrong that is not in the list, for example "dog" it will show error.If I spell go south like this "go suth" it will show error, but if I spell it like this "go soutg" it closes the game. Is there a way to make it go to error for misspelled word like "go soutg" , without having to list the ways to misspell the word?

Comment: `goto open drawer` will got to label `open` and ignore `drawer`.
Besides that your code works fine here.

Comment: The thing is that I need to find a way were it does not close the game if I misspell something.I don't want to type every way to misspell a word into the batch file.

Comment: I tried your code. It works as expected when I enter nonsense (it echoes "error" and pauses). It doesn't work, if I enter one of the expected answers (of course, because the labels are not defined in that code-snippet). I get a "label not found" and the batchfile stopps. I can imagine, that one of your labels does not exist (or is misspelled)

Comment: You can use `if /i ...` to ignore capitalization, then `go south`, `Go South`, gO sOuTh`... are all matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems to be quite OK, the issue you are experiencing won't be caused by typo, but by `goto` statements in several cases.

CMD interpreter is taking space as delimiter of arguments, so you cannot use `goto take money` as that will actually interpret as `goto take` and will ignore `money`, that would lead the code to non-existing label.

Certainly use as suggested `IF /I` which will help you to ignore case sensitive kind of typos, especially when the user will not see list of options.

If user/player will see list of possibilities, you may also consider to use `choice` command instead of `set /p` as you can define exact choices where user will just selection option using single key and will set variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` to specific value (based on selection made) and you can then do compare like this `IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "3" goto east`

Benefit of utilizing `choice` command is that only defined options would be accepted, while any other non-defined options user will do, will just make the speeker to beep. Thanks to that you don't need to redirect the script again back to the same prompt "redrawing" the content, etc... but just a suggestion

Hope this helps... Ricky